# Strange Response.Redirect behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I noticed a strange behaviour in Response.Redirect with the following code:

```
private void MsgRedirect(string msg)
{
     HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Message.aspx?pMsg=" + msg, false);
}
```

I tested with a parameter like "There is an error." and it does nothing. It doesn't throw any exception and it doesn't redirect.

With the same parameter, but with this code, it works:

```
private void MsgRedirect(string msg)
{
     HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Message.aspx?pMsg=" + msg.ToString(), false);
}
```

Can someone please explain me why?

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

---- Edit 1

I had that behaviour because I'm using Telerik RadAjax, so i had to do the redirect with

```
RadAjaxManager.Redirect
```

Comment: There is no functional difference between the codes, calling `ToString` on a string returns the string itself. If one code works and the other one doesn't, then it's not because of that difference that you show, but because of something else somewhere else in the code.

Comment: You may have problems with invalid characters in your parameter (spaces, periods?). You may have to URL encode your error message.

Comment: If you could tell us what msg is? Could you show what it looks like?

Comment: For example, trying with msg="There is an error." it doesn't work.
But now I'm investigating on what @Guffa suggested, because I tried creating a new page with just the call to MsgRedirect and it works.